# Wordpress multisite como postar uma vez em todos os sites

Tags: wordpress

Minha duvida é a seguinte.

Tenho dois temas que criei, um é o principal, tem dois campos personalizados para post, onde eu colocaria tudo o conteúdo nele, na hora de exibir, ele me mostraria apenas uma parte do post, e o outro tema, a outra parte ate ai tudo bem, o problema é, como duplicar esse post automaticamente nos dois sites?

Eu preciso que ao fazer um post, todos os sites automaticamente postassem o mesmo conteúdo, uma copia.

Não sei se fui claro o suficiente.

Comment: Aponte todos os domínios para o mesmo wordpress, e selecione o tema com base no `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: Na hora do `save_post`, você tem que fazer um `switch_to_blog` e atualizar os outros sites. Só com essas duas keywords você já encontra algo no [so] ou no [wordpress.se]. Se puder pesquisar, e não dando certo, é só editar a pergunta com algo de código e dar um toque.